# Toshiba satellite L855-12R overheats

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I bought a Toshiba Satellite L855-12R several months ago and started playing Assassin's Creed. Whenever I play this game or any other game, it starts to overheat. I tried restarting the computer several times but it has not helped. Could this be due to a virus or another problem?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which graphics card does the laptop have? **Please update your question, by editing it.**

Comment: Unless you have a dedicated gaming computer with a very high quality GPU, you will likely encounter overheating when playing a game like Assassin's Creed.

Comment: It could be that built-in cooler inside your notebook has a product-failure and is not working properly ? You have warranty, ... then send it in to Toshiba to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Windows, just use a cooler, or maybe your laptop simply have physical issue
if you have Ubuntu try to use ATI's drivers, in system settings you have special category for that